# colors change after texture load

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 1 on Android. I have several objects, that don't use textures and one, that uses one.

When I render the textured element all colors change to the background color of my texture.
Even trying to set back the "default" color (glColor(1,1,1,1);) doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

to render the texture. Before rendering the non-texture elements, you should call

```
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```